# Using gmaps api with key

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to call GMaps-API to geocode in PHP. When i use it without key it works, but if i use it with key on the URL it does not return any value. I want to pay per use in case i get over the 2.500 limit each day.

So this works:

```
$peticion="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=STA.+MARIA+MAGDALENA%2C+16,28016,MADRID&sensor=false";
$res=file_get_contents($peticion);
```

and this does not work:

```
$peticion="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=STA.+MARIA+MAGDALENA%2C+16,28016,MADRID&sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY";
$res=file_get_contents($peticion);
```

I have an api key on google developper console. And the last link, on browser works ... so what am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Your string works fine with my key, so the problem in the key. Is it a browser key without any restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem is to download https. used the following:

```
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```